# How can I change the left parameter as String while writing in my Firebase Realtime Database in Functions?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

My Code to write into the database:

```
rdb.ref(`users/${userid}`).update({
            name : username,
            `${mystring}` : 1,
            `${mystring2}` : 2
        });
```

The connection and the writing works, but only the first line.
In JavaScript the Syntax to pass a variable to a String should be :

```
`string${variable}`
```

Am I wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: In javascript you need to add brackets around a template string key: `{ [\`${string}\`]: value }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Jeremy said, Strings need brackets around:

```
rdb.ref(`users/${userid}`).update({
            name : username,
            [`${mystring}`] : 1,
            [`${mystring2}`] : 2
        });
```

Comment: You can accept your answer so that the community knows that there is an answer that has helped the OP.